# How can I use the javaScript value in php

Tags: javascript, php, loops

### I have a question about using javaScript value in PHP:

```
var i; <br>
for(i=0;i<4;i++){ <br>
    alert("echo $MarkA[i]");<br>
}
```

`$MarkA` is a PHP array
I want to know that how can I using the javascript value 'i' in PHP code.
Thanks.

Comment: alert("echo".$MarkA[i]);<br>`

Comment: can you please paste your above and below code, need to see how you want to use this...

Comment: can ajax solve your problem? you can pass javascript value into php using ajax.

Comment: var i; 
  for(i=0;i<<?echo count($IDA)?>;i++){ 
   alert(<?php echo $MarkA[i]?>);
   
  }

Answer (score 4):

That's not how PHP works. You can't mix client and server-side scripts that way. One option is creating a JavaScript variable:

```
<script>
   var marks = <?php echo json_encode($MarkA);?>;
   for(i=0;i<4;i++) alert(marks[i]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use client side script variable into server side script. But you can parse the PHP array using the below method. No need javascript increment variable.

```
<?php $MarkA = array(1,2,3,4);?>

<script>
var json = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($MarkA);?>");

$.each(json,function (i,item) {
    console.log(item);
});
</script>
```